# XSLT remove unwanted xmlns from xslt result

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML that contains an XML as a string:

```
<Result>
    <XML>
       &lt;PingRS xmlns="http://www.test.com"&gt;
          &lt;Message&gt;
             Hello.
          &lt;/Message&gt;
      &lt;/PingRS&gt;
    </XML>
</Result>
```

I am transforming this using this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:template match="/Result">
    <xsl:value-of select="XML" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To get this result:

```
<PingRS xmlns="http://www.test.com">
    <Message>Hello.</Message>
</PingRS>
```

I want to remove this `xmlns` attribute in the same XSLT file. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you transform twice (either different stylesheets or the same stylesheet)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's possible, but since the `<XML>` element does **not** contain XML, it must be done through string manipulation:

```
<xsl:template match="/Result">
<xsl:variable name="xmlns" select="' xmlns=&quot;http://www.test.com&quot;'" />
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(XML, $xmlns)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(XML, $xmlns)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>
```

---

BTW, the result that you show is incorrect - what you're really getting is:

```
   <PingRS xmlns="http://www.test.com">
      <Message>
         Hello.
      </Message>
  </PingRS>
```

---

**EDIT:**

if the contents of xmlns are unknown in advance, you could use:

```
<xsl:template match="/Result">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(XML, ' xmlns=&quot;')" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(XML, ' xmlns=&quot;'), '&quot;')" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks. And if the content of the xmlns will be changed, can I use regex in the select? Like `select="'xmlns=&quot;*&quot;'"`?

Comment: @bale3 You cannot use regex in XSLT 1.0; you just need to use a bit more elaborate string manipulation -  see the edit to my answer.

Comment: The answer is using string manipulation. String manipulation in XSLT suffers from the same weaknesses as XML processing with strings in any programming language. I.e. the XSLT works in exactly this scenario, but not for equivalent XMLs such as `<Result>
  <XML>
       &lt;x:PingRS xmlns:x="http://www.test.com"&gt;
          &lt;y:Message xmlns:y="http://www.test.com"&gt;
             Hello.
          &lt;/y:Message&gt;
      &lt;/x:PingRS&gt;
    </XML>
</Result>`. So if you have no control over the input, the given solution may not work.

Comment: @ThomasW. 1. The given input contains a string that needs to be modified; hence string manipulation is required. 2. In general, XSLT works for input in the format (grammar, schema) for which it was designed; this is not limited to strings.